# Kivy Plyer GPS JVM exception

Tags: android, gps, kivy

I'm writing a GPS aircraft navigation app in `Kivy`. It runs well on all the devices I have tested it on including various phones and the Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1" but fails on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 8". Assuming a faulty device I sent it back and got another one. Same problem.

Using Tito's GPSdemo app and trapping the exception, 
at the self.gps.start() line it throws:

```
File "jnius_utils.pxi", line 43, in jnius.jnius.check_exception 
(jnius/jnius.c3316) JavaException: JVM exception occured.
```

The 8" tab is a good size device for my app so I'd like to use it. Other GPS apps work fine on it including GPS Arrow Pro and Sky Demon for example.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
The code is:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import gps
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: app.gps_location
    Label:
        text: app.gps_status
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        padding: '4dp'
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Start' if self.state == 'normal' else 'Stop'
            on_state: app.gps.start() if self.state == 'down' else app.gps.stop()
'''

class GpsTest(App):

    gps_location = StringProperty()
    gps_status = StringProperty('')

    def build(self):
        self.gps = gps
        try:
            self.gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location, on_status=self.on_status)
            self.gps.start() #exception occurs here 
        except:
            import traceback;
            import sys; 
            formatted_lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
            self.gps_status = formatted_lines[-2]+'\n'+formatted_lines[-1]
            print self.gps_status

        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.gps_location = '\n'.join(['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])

    def on_status(self, stype, status):
        self.gps_status = 'type={}\n{}'.format(stype, status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GpsTest().run()
```

Comment: Please provide segments of your code.  How is anyone supposed to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need to show the actual error. This is a Java exception; there will be a Java stack trace and exception info in the logcat.